# Humans in 83% earth gravity?

Tags: science-based, physics, gravity

A planet I’m working on has 83% earth gravity. What would this be like for a human visiting the planet?

Comment: Can you flesh out your question with a bit more detail of what you might mean by "what would this be like?" At the moment your question is not telling us anything that could lead to evidence based answers - except of book-length scope. Also, what humans? Can you [edit] to give us more, and narrow it down to be answerable.

Answer (score 5):

For a visitor?

It would feel **perfectly normal, possibly even a bit invigorating.**

You would be a bit clumsy in normal activities, and very clumsy in active sports, until acclimated.

DON'T try something like trick skateboarding until you have your gravity legs. Muscle memory of complex, gravity-timed actions will be off.

Expect to fall or at least trip going down stairs.
The stairs will very possibly have taller risers making them steeper. At the same time you will be bouncing higher as you step. The combo could be a pratfall.

It might actually be more dangerous with regards to trips and falls than a very low gravity world.
Gravity is still high enough for falls to be fast and violent, but your timing will be off, yet the gravity is close enough to normal that it might not trigger the sensation of "different environment", putting your motor skills on high alert. It would feel like everyday ordinary, until *boom*

Comment: I like this answer.  But I suspect the pratfalls would come more from unexpected *inertia*.  Many of us are accustomed to gaining and losing weight - but when you *feel* light and then go to turn around impulsively and you have as much mass as ever ... that might be what gets you.

Comment: @MikeSerfas exactly. also simple things, like pouring a coffee. The water stream will move just a bit slower, and spout out further than expected. small things, but the world will be just a bit out of synch. And worst, it will be so slight as to not really *feel* wrong, so your body will not be in alert mode watching every single movement.

Answer (score 3):

## Not Particularly Uncomfortable

If they're there for a while, they might suffer some muscle atrophy/bone demineralization, but a 17% reduction in gravity is pretty tame.  Otherwise, they'll feel slightly stronger than they do on Earth, and will be a *little* uncoordinated at first.

To explain the lack of coordination: Earth humans are accustomed to a certain weight corresponding to a certain mass, and that association is reflexive.  Something you could slightly more easily lift would still have the same mass, so moving it in an arc would feel the same as on Earth, but up and down would feel different, and that would take a little getting used to.  Likewise, stairs would be a bit more dangerous, because while messing up stride length on level ground can, at worst, result in tripping, messing up stride length on stairs could result in a painful tumble.

Other than that, it'd be pretty normal.

Comment: Rather like the day after a two-week backpacking trip, when you have to get used to walking without that extra 40 lbs or so (say 20% of your body weight).